# On mouse over enable button after 3 seconds, on mouse off disable and stop count down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that does something irreversible and I'm trying to put a lockout on it unless the user hovers over it for 3 seconds. If they wait 3 seconds the button becomes enabled. As soon as they mouse off it disables again. If they also mouse off during the count down of 3 seconds it stops the count down.

```
    $('#delete_btn').on('mouseover', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#delete_btn').prop('disabled', false)
        }, 3000)
    })

    $('#delete_btn').on('mouseout', function () {
            $('#delete_btn').prop('disabled', true)
    })
```

I'm not sure how to stop the count down if they mouse out early

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the timeout. So, it's ready to fire on the next call:

```
    var timeout;

    $('#delete_btn').on('mouseover', function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $('#delete_btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }, 3000);
    });

    $('#delete_btn').on('mouseout', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $('#delete_btn').prop('disabled', true);
    });
```

See it in work at CodePen:

https://codepen.io/aminshahrokhi/pen/VNJBYZ

Answer (score 1):

this a copy-paste from W3School, basiclly you have to 'save' the timeout into a var, an then, on hover, clear the time out:

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

I hope this helps :)